# Convert Javascript Array to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP script with curl's an external site which returns a javascript array that looks like this:

array[0]='some stuff'

array[1]='some more stuff'

I would like to take this and convert it into a PHP array so I can reference it later down in the script for echoing. Is this the way to go about doing it? Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add a $ to array, then a ; at the end of each line?

Comment: This would make it into an array that PHP would accept, but at that stage it's still sitting in the variable that curl dumped it into. How can I convert that into a PHP array I can access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a String array, you can use regular expressions:

with this:

```
preg_match( "\[(\d+)\]='(.*)'" , $curlString , $matches )
```

you can obtain the index, and the value:

i.e, response of curl:

```
 array[0] = 'abc';
 array[1] = 'xyz';
```

before preg_match, the value of $matches was:

```
 $matches[0] == '0';
 $matches[1] == 'abc';
 $matches[1] == '1';
 $matches[2] == 'xyz';
```

And with something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < len($matches);$i +=2)
     $finalArray[$matches[i]] = $matches[i+1];
```

the $finalArray has the same values of "array"

This code can contain errors.

Answer (score 0):

if your javascript page return JSON (Javascripit object notation) in http request, you can tranform it in php array with json_decode() php function.

Comment: Unfortunately it returns only what I posted above. A javascript format array in plain text.